# Django sortable many to many relationship?

Tags: django

I want to set up a many to many relationship between two models, Gallery and Image. I would like to be able to sort them in the site admin in order to change the order the images appear in a gallery on the frontend.

Is there anything built into Django which will help me do this?
I don't want to reinvent the wheel!

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing built-in, no. There's [`order_with_respect_to`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to), but that's for ForeignKeys and doesn't really expose any functionality in the admin.

A quick Google reveals [django-sortedm2m](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sortedm2m/), which I haven't used but is by Gregor Müllegger, who's contributed a fair amount to Django, so is likely to be reliable.